# Not able to remove the beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are using following code to show default pop up on refresh, tab close events

```
var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

myEvent(chkevent, function (e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
  if ($('#timeExpiredtxt').hasClass('hide') && $("#submittedAnsResponseText").hasClass("hide")) {
    var confirmationMessage = 'You are attempting an assessment. Are you sure you want to leave this assessment?';
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
  }
});
```

I want to remove and unbind this event at runtime. I tried the following code but no luck.

```
$(window).off("beforeunload"); 
$(window).off("onbeforeunload"); 
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

$(window).unbind("beforeunload");

Comment: Are you sure its not a caching problem?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: @HelloWorld we're in 2018. Why use high level languages? Assembler and Machine code work fine

Comment: @Rory JavaScript is pretty cross-browser/platform now. jQuery should become a thing of the past. It's mostly overhead these days.

Comment: Granny - It is not a caching issue.

Comment: HelloWorld - I want to unbind those events. Jquery or document.getElementById, classList, addEventListener and removeEventListener will also do.just need solution

Comment: Cross platform is arguable if you need legacy IE support. jQuery is much more succinct than JS and very much still has a place. Either way this isn't a constructive or on topic discussion, so there's no point continuing it

Comment: @ganesh var myFunction = function () {}; window.addEventListener("beforeunload", myFunction); window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", myFunction); should work?

Comment: HelloWorld tried that it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the event binding code.

```
function closeIt() {
    if ($('#timeExpiredtxt').hasClass('hide') && $("#submittedAnsResponseText").hasClass("hide")) {
        return "Any string value here forces a dialog box to \n" +
             "appear before closing the window.";
    }
}
window.onbeforeunload = closeIt;
```

and unbind used below code

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```